# комментарии в VSC при сохранении с русского поменялись на абракадабру

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code, lua

Пытаюсь использовать VSC для написания скриптов на lua — настроил, все было нормально, но при очередном "сохранении как…"., комментарии с русского поменялись на абракадабру. Причем, другой код который не "пере сохранял" — там все норм. Я понимаю что при сохранении произошло изменение кодировки — только как исправить не знаю! Если писать новый код - то все нормально!

Уточняю - Visual Studio Code

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что такое VSC.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте кодировку в VSC и самого конечного файла.

Для начала измените кодировку в VSC. После этого откройте файл с исходным кодом в любом текстовом редакторе (например блокноте) и поменяйте кодировку самого файла.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]